# Multiple selection of dataframe using multiple column slices

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a dataframe that has 10 columns, I am trying select columns 1 to 3 (first to third) and columns 5 to 8 (fifth to eighth). Is it possible to select using the iloc selector so that it can take multiple slices. The sample below can slice first to third, I would like to add the columns 5 to 8 as well

```
df = pc_df.iloc[:,0:4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
#import  numpy as np
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:4, 5:9]]
```

`np.r_` will concatenate the indexes for you.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out for a while just couldn't get my head around it. This np.r_ solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't know about np.r_, so also thanks to Tito from me!

If you don't want to use extra lib, you could also use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:4], df.iloc[:, 5:9]],1)
```

Comment: Worked as well. I had tried something similar but missed out the concat, the enclosing square bracket and the 1 at the end.

Comment: The np.r_ is new to me too, will add it to my reading list.